# How to bind XMLListCollection into Model?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid, model, mxml

When the XMLListCollection is updated in the DataGrid, I want it to add the XML (bind it) into the Model.  How would I do this?  Or if not possible, how would I manually add XML into the Model?

This is a rough example of what I'm trying to do.  Adding data to the DataGrid works fine; it just doesn't go into the Model when sending to the HTTPService.

```
<mx:Model id="model">
  <root><colors>{collection}</colors></root>
</mx:Model>
<mx:XMLListCollection id="collection" />

<mx:Label text="Input color:" />
<mx:TextInput id="color" />
<mx:Button label="Add Color" click="addColor();" />
<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{collection}">
  <mx:columns>
    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="color" headerText="Color" />
  </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
<mx:Button label="Submit" click="submit();" />

<mx:Script><![CDATA[
  // imports...

  public function addColor():void {
    var xml:XML = new XML(<color></color>);
    xml.color = color.text;
    collection.addItem(xml);
    Alert.show(collection.toXMLString()); // xml looks fine and shows up in datagrid
    // how to do something like this?
    // model.appendChild(xml); // doesn't work
  }

  public function submit():void {
    var serv:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
    // setup serv...
    serv.send(model); // server just gets "<colors></colors>"
  }
]]></mx:Script>
```

Thanks!

### EDIT:

Thanks guys for your answers!  It ended up leading to my solution.  I had to use XMLListCollection because adding 2 or more elements to the DataGrid never worked with either XML or XMLList for whatever reason (and I tried {variable},{variable.colors},{variable.colors.color},{variable.color},etc. all possibilities).  I think that I can use a Model, but I changed it to XML below so that you can see the output with toXMLString().  Lastly, I have to use a Model or XML because this is just a small example of the large project (I showed this by adding OtherData below).  Thanks again.  Here's a working example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

  <mx:XML id="data">
    <colors>
    </colors>
  </mx:XML>

  <mx:XMLListCollection id="collection" source="{data.color}" />

  <mx:XML id="model">
    <root>
      <otherData>{otherData.text}</otherData>
      <colors>{data}</colors>
    </root>
  </mx:XML>

  <mx:Label text="Input color:" />
  <mx:TextInput id="color" />
  <mx:Button label="Add Color" click="addColor();" />
  <mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{collection}">
    <mx:columns>
      <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="color" headerText="Color" />
    </mx:columns>
  </mx:DataGrid>
  <mx:Label text="Other data:" />
  <mx:TextInput id="otherData" />
  <mx:Button label="Submit" click="submit();" />

  <mx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.controls.*;

    public function addColor():void {
      var xml:XML = new XML(<color></color>);
      xml.color = color.text;
      collection.addItem(xml);
      Alert.show(collection.toXMLString()); // xml looks fine and shows up in datagrid
    }

    public function submit():void {
      Alert.show(model.toXMLString());
    }
  ]]></mx:Script>

</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are few misunderstood things on your part:

```
<root><colors>{collection}</colors></root>
```

you probably expect this to bind `collection` to the child node of `<colors/>` node, while what it does is an E4X string substitution, so no binding is created here.

```
var xml:XML = new XML(<color><value></value></color>);
```

should really be:

```
var xml:XML = <color><value/></color>;
```

XML has special literal syntax in AS3, what you used to create a new XML is already an XML, so essentially, you did it twice. Nodes having no text value are normalized to be shorter, so you trying to write them in the way you do will have no effect.

`XMLListCollection` is actually a useless class, not sure why does it even exist. You can specify `XML` or `XMLList` as a data provider for the `DataGrid`. `Model` is another useless class, so, probably, you could just loose it and replace it with `dataGrid.dataProvider` where you would need to reference the content of the DataGrid.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say the XMLListCollection is useles...it works to allow XML to be used as a dataprovider and generate all the change events, etc., similar to how ArrayCollection allows Arrays to be bound to as a dataProvider and the list to update as items are added and removed. The Class that is useless here is Model. I don't see any point to it here (and have never found a use case for it). In this case, why not just server.send(<root><colors>{collection.source as XMLList}</colors></root>);? This assumes the server actually needs all that extra nesting and isn't just stripping it off...

Comment: Otherwise, you could just use server.send(collection.source);

Comment: Thanks, please see my Edit at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Hm, that's odd; I'm using v4.1, and my code works.  Also, I'm using the free mxmlc compiler and not FlashBuilder.  Maybe it's broken in versions higher than 4.1?